# Pyside scroll two qtextedits simultaneously

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyside

I have two subclasses. One implements qplaintextedit, the other qtextedit. The qtextedit is being used to show line numbers for the qplaintextedit. My problem is getting the two to scroll at the same time. I have tried self.viewport().scroll(), that does not actually do anything. I have tried connecting the qscrollbars, but the maximum of the qplaintextedit is smaller than the qtextedit's. I have tried I have tried several other solutions to line numbers, and they do not allow you to use stylesheets on them. Is there a way of scrolling both simultaneously, or failing that an approach to line numbers which is styleable? I am using pyside with python 2.7. Here is the code I am using at the moment.

```
class NumberBar(QTextEdit):
def __init__(self):
    super(NumberBar,self).__init__()
    self.count = 1
    self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.width = self.fontMetrics().width(unicode(10000))
    self.setFixedWidth(self.width)
    self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;border:0px;")
    self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.NoTextInteraction)
    self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
    self.curse = QTextCursor(self.document())
    self.curse.insertText(str(1))
def change(self, new):
    if new > self.count:
        self.curse.movePosition(self.curse.End)
        self.curse.insertBlock()
        self.curse.insertText(str(new+1))
        self.count = new
    else:
        self.curse.movePosition(self.curse.End)
        self.curse.select(self.curse.BlockUnderCursor)
        self.curse.removeSelectedText()
        self.count = new
    print self.verticalScrollBar().minimum(),self.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
def onload(self, new):
    while(new > self.count):
        self.curse.movePosition(self.curse.End)
        self.curse.insertBlock()
        self.curse.insertText(str(self.count+1))
        self.count += 1
def updateContents(self, rect, scroll):
    if scroll:
        print scroll
        self.viewport().scroll(0, scroll)
        self.update()
    else:
        self.update()

class Editor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,text = None,name=None):
        super(Editor,self).__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.number_bar = NumberBar()
        self.edit = TextEdit(self.number_bar,text)
        highlighter = highlight.Highlighter(self.edit.document(),name)
        #self.edit.blockCountChanged.connect(self.number_bar.adjustWidth)
        self.edit.updateRequest.connect(self.number_bar.updateContents)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.number_bar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class TextEdit(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self,numbar,text = None):
        super(TextEdit,self).__init__(text)
        sheet = open("sheet.css",'r').read()
        self.setStyleSheet(sheet)
        self.setLineWrapMode(self.NoWrap)
        self.setViewportMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.document().blockCountChanged.connect(numbar.change)
        numbar.onload(0 if not text else text.count('\n'))
        self.numbar = numbar
        numbar.verticalScrollBar().show()
```

I have tried the code [here](http://john.nachtimwald.com/2009/08/19/better-qplaintextedit-with-line-numbers/), but that can not be styled by a style sheet.

Comment: Could you provide some running sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a full example that does just what you want.

[**Code Editor Example**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-codeeditor-example.html)

Translating to Python shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Can you style it with a stylesheet? That is one of my requirements.